# How to override a function python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, overriding

I have some code I'd like to quickly test.  This code includes a line that needs to query a server and obtain a True/False answer:

```
result = server.queryServer(data)
```

Is there a way to override this function call so that it just calls a local function that always returns True (so that I can debug without running the server)?

Comment: `result = True or server.queryServer(data)` will always return True, without calling a function

Comment: @Vinny: but that's not what the OP is anking for. They are isolating their code from dependencies to see if it'll react correctly when the *external*  `server.queryServer()` call behaves in a certain way. They are not trying to break their code here.

Answer (score 1):

[Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) is your friend. It allows you to mock entire classes or functions of them.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called *mocking*, replacing existing objects with temporary objects that act differently just for a test.

Use the [`unittest.mock` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) to do this. It will create the temporary objects for you, and give you the tools to replace the object, and restore the old situation, for the duration of a test.

The module provides [*patchers*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-patchers) to do the replacement. For example, you could use a context manager:

```
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch('server.queryServer') as mocked_queryServer:
    mocked_queryServer.return_value = True  # always return True when called
    # test your code
    # ...

    # afterwards, check if the mock has been called at least once.
    mocked_queryServer.assert_called()
```

I added an assertion at the end there; mock objects not only let you replace functions transparently, they then also record what happens to them, letting you check if your code worked correctly by calling the mock.